# Swift check NSDate is not nil

Tags: swift, nsdate

I'm getting a value from userDefaults which might be nil or might be an NSDate, so I want to check since I need to act on that date. How would I correctly do the check?

```
        let timeAtQuit: NSDate = (userDefaults.objectForKey("timeAtQuit") as NSDate)

    if(timeAtQuit){ Type 'NSDate' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

    if(timeAtQuit != nil){ // 'NSDate' is not convertible to 'UInt8'

    another attempt:
        var timeAtQuit:NSDate? = (userDefaults.objectForKey("timeAtQuit") as NSDate)

    if(timeAtQuit != nil){
        let timeSinceQuit:Double = timeAtQuit.timeIntervalSinceNow // 'NSDate?' does not have a member named 'timeIntervalSinceNow'
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use optional binding (`if let`) with an optional cast (`as?`):

```
if let timeAtQuit = userDefaults.objectForKey("timeAtQuit") as? NSDate {
    println(timeAtQuit)
} else {
    // default value is not set or not an NSDate
}
```

---

With

```
let timeAtQuit: NSDate = (userDefaults.objectForKey("timeAtQuit") as NSDate)
```

you are forcefully casting the return  value to `NSDate`, so this
will crash at runtime if the value is not set or not an `NSDate`.
The same happens in

```
var timeAtQuit:NSDate? = (userDefaults.objectForKey("timeAtQuit") as NSDate)
```

It does not help that the expression is assigned to an optional `NSDate?`, the crash already occurs when evaluating the right-hand side.
The compiler error at

```
let timeSinceQuit:Double = timeAtQuit.timeIntervalSinceNow
```

occurs because `timeAtQuit` is an optional here, so you would have to
unwrap it

```
let timeSinceQuit:Double = timeAtQuit!.timeIntervalSinceNow
```

Comment: thanks very much for clarification Martin, I'm really stuggling with getting my head around optional and unwrapping in swift, I appreciate your thoughtful answer, thanks again