# swift check if NSDate is nil without let

Tags: swift

I find very messy to use let to verify if a variable is nil or had been set a value previously.

```
var birthDate: NSDate?
```

There is a form where user can set their birthdate and this variable is assigned a value.

Later in the doSave method I want to verify if this field was filled

```
@IBAction func doSave(sender: AnyObject) {
...
if birthDate == nil {
    doAlert("You need to specify your birth date")
} else { ... continue save ... }
```

The best approach I had obtained is to create a second variable, based on [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140895/swift-check-nsdate-is-not-nil)

```
if let bd = birthDate! as? NSDate { ... continue save ... }
else { doAlert("You need to specify your birth date") }
```

I only get a warning: Conditional cast from 'NSDate' to 'NSDate' always succeeds

Is this the only way to achieve this. Is there anything less messy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var birthDate: NSDate?

if let birthDate = birthDate {
    println(birthDate.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())!)
} else {
    println("birthDate is nil")
}

birthDate = NSDate()
if let birthDate = birthDate {
    println(birthDate.descriptionWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale())!)
} else {
    println("birthDate is nil")
}
```

Comment: I found it is possible to compare to nil, I don't know if this was allowed in the later versions of swift because I remember it was not possible, however now it doesn't create a warning or error anymore.  I prefer to check: "if birthDate != nil' but I haven't found documentation to know if this is really correct or just accepted for back compatibility, and if there are other unsafe implications of using nil comparisons. I prefer to accept this answer because it follows the recommended way and because this was the first one because I liked also the other two answers.

Comment: @Haac74 you can compare it to nil as long as you declare it as optional (NSDate?)

Answer (score 1):

In this you are not performing a check:

```
if let bd = birthDate! as? NSDate { ... continue save ... }
else { doAlert("You need to specify your birth date") }
```

What you want to do is optionally unwrap the birthdate to an `NSDate`, what you are doing is forcing the `NSDate?` to `NSDate`, then you are checking if that `NSDate` is an `NSDate` (which it always is, the warning originates here). If it is, you are putting this into variable `bd`.

Written very long, you are doing this:

```
// force unwrap birthdate: birthDate!
if birthDate == nil {
    // this crashes the program
} else {
    if birthDate! is NSDate { // birthDate as? NSDate
        let bd = birthDate as! NSDate
        // Here ... continue save ... occurs
    } else {
        doAlert("You need to specify your birth date")
    }
}
```

As you can see, you are forcing the unwrap first, and then checking if it exists.

You should do the following using `if let`-syntax:

```
if let bd = birthDate {
    // continue save
} else {
    doAlert("You need to specify your birth date")
}
```

This translates to the following code:

```
    if birthDate != nil { // birthDate as? NSDate
        let bd = birthDate!
        // Continue save
    } else {
        doAlert("You need to specify your birth date")
    }
```

Comment: I like this answer because you showed me my mistake, however the first reply answered also, with less explanation but I think this way is more fair.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
if let bd = birthDate! as? NSDate
```

with

```
if birthDate != nil
```

Comment: I remember this was not possible, however I find this can be done now. I would like to know why that happened in swift. I like this more but I will look for the reasons this was not allowed before.